# How to group multiple columns in jquery datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

How to collapse and expand the table based on multiple columns grouping.

For example I have table like this

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
location   |   size   | cont_no |   price  |  depot  |  cond  |
---------------------------------------------------------------
   USA     |    XX    |   123   |    230   |   SED   |    LK  |
   USA     |    YY    |   343   |    330   |   ASD   |    HK  |
   UAE     |    XX    |   233   |    230   |   SED   |    LK  |
   IND     |    ZZ    |   123   |    230   |   SAD   |    FK  |
   IND     |    XX    |   213   |    430   |   ASD   |    KK  |
   IND     |    YY    |   433   |    870   |   GFD   |    FK  |
   USA     |    YY    |   865   |    230   |   SED   |    LK  |
   UAE     |    XX    |   976   |    430   |   SED   |    HK  |
   USA     |    ZZ    |   342   |    230   |   CCD   |    HK  |
   UAE     |    XX    |   132   |    445   |   SED   |    KK  |
   UAE     |    ZZ    |   064   |    323   |   YYD   |    LK  |
   IND     |    YY    |   452   |    130   |   ITG   |    HK  |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is how I need to group the above table

```
  -------------------------------
    location |  XX  |  YY  |  ZZ  |
    -------------------------------
       UAE   |   3  |   0  |   1  |
       USA   |   1  |   2  |   1  |
       IND   |   1  |   2  |   1  |
    -------------------------------
```

I want to group based on location and size column, Eg: USA has 3 XX and 0 YY and 1 ZZ,

And then when i click the row i want to expand and show those 3 XX and 0 YY and 1 ZZ other four column  cont_no, price, depot, cond

please someone help me or give me some suggestion or link for reference.

Thank you

Comment: This sounds like something that would be easier using two different tables, and hiding/showing tables and columns depending on the user interaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what your trying to make !

check the following question and answer

[DataTables hidden row details example - the table header is misplaced (test case attached)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18697986/datatables-hidden-row-details-example-the-table-header-is-misplaced-test-case)

JSFIDDLE [Sample 1](http://jsbin.com/oZEGIPu/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

JSFIDDLE [Sample 2](http://jsbin.com/IgEHAfi/1/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 1):

It could be done as shown in [Row details](http://datatables.net/examples/server_side/row_details.html) example.

The trick would be to pre-process the data and perform the calculations and grouping with JavaScript before giving data to DataTables. This would depend on where your data comes from, static table or Ajax request. If you're producing the data on the server, this could be done server-side as well.

Basically the result data in JSON format could be as shown below. This will simplify working with child rows in DataTables.

```
[
   { 
      "location": "UAE",
      "XX": 2,
      "YY": 0,
      "ZZ": 1,
      "details": [
         ["UAE","XX","123","230","SED","LK"],
         // more records for the same location
      ]
   },
   // more locations
]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can hack your way through other libs. will it worth the effort??.

or you can use **Tabulator**. which has multi column grouping.

example :

```js
  //load data as json
    var tableData = [
        {id:1, name:"Billy Bob", age:"12", gender:"male", height:1, col:"red", dob:"", cheese:1},
        {id:2, name:"Mary May", age:"1", gender:"female", height:2, col:"blue", dob:"14/05/1982", cheese:true},
        {id:3, name:"Christine Lobowski", age:"42", height:0, col:"green", dob:"22/05/1982", cheese:"true"},
        {id:4, name:"Brendon Philips", age:"125", gender:"male", height:1, col:"orange", dob:"01/08/1980"},
        {id:5, name:"Margret Marmajuke", age:"16", gender:"female", height:5, col:"yellow", dob:"31/01/1999"},
        {id:6, name:"Billy Bob", age:"12", gender:"male", height:1, col:"red", dob:"", cheese:1},
    ]
    
    var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
        height:"311px",
        layout:"fitColumns",
         groupBy:function(data){ 
            return data.gender + " - " + data.age; //groups by data and age
        },
    autoColumns:true,
    });    

    table.setData(tableData);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.2.7/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.2.7/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div id="example-table"></div>
```

---

the only table lib that can group by multi col  is Tabulator, AFAIK.

here are the other table  libs.

```
                   -------- group by  -------
                   single column | multi column 
tabulator       :        yes     | yes
bootstrap-table :        yes     | no
datatables.net  :        yes     | no
dynatable.js    :        no      | no
```

tabulator has bootstrap , simple white theme:

- theme overview : http://tabulator.info/docs/4.1/theme
- live view themes : http://tabulator.info/examples/4.1?#theming

read more:

- http://tabulator.info/docs/4.2/group
- https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_grouping.html
- https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/index.html#extensions/group-by-v2.html